# Colouring the boundary of same-colored block of pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I've got an image with 5 different colors; in this case, randomly generated:

```
w, h = 40, 27
img = Image.new("RGB", (w,h))
pixels = img.load()

available_colors = {
    'r': (255, 13, 18),
    'b': (72, 64, 255),
    'y': (236, 236, 1),
    'p': (208, 1, 239),
    'g': (37, 252, 32),
}

for i in range(w):
  for j in range(h):
     pixels[i,j] = random.choice(list(available_colors.values()))

img = img.resize((15*w,15*h), Image.NEAREST)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Given an arbitrary pixel in the image, I wonder if I can color the boundary of the same-colored contiguous block it belongs to (in this case I colored the two outermost pixels black).

Here, for example, is the expected result when given the pixel `(0,0)`:

[image]

In my research and efforts, I found this to be a surprisingly hard problem, esp. as someone who doesn't come from computer vision and doesn't really know what to look for (just to mention several different keywords I came across like boundary tracing, edge detection, contour detection, ...). Probably it's a rather easy task when knowing which package (OpenCV?) and algorithm to use...

Comment: It should be a simple *"floodfill"* see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill It's late here, so if you haven't worked it out yourself, I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the reference. I've experimented a bit with floodfill but haven't managed to produce the expected result yet. In fact, I found it a bit unpredictable, e.g., with it coloring the whole image or nothing at all. I would very much welcome your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% certain exactly where you want to get to with this, so I *"did some things"* and you can pick and choose techniques that are useful to you. Each little block of code does one specific thing and creates an output image of that phase of processing.

I mixed up **PIL** and **OpenCV** by doing things the way they come to me - it is probably possible to do it all with just one library, but life is too short...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Load image, ensuring RGB not palette
im = Image.open('start.png').convert('RGB')

# Floodfill with white from top-left corner
ImageDraw.floodfill(im, (0,0), value=(255,255,255))
im.save('DEBUG-phase1.png')

# Make into Numpy array and zero all non-white pixels
na = np.array(im)
na = cv2.cvtColor(na, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
orig = na.copy()
na[~np.all(na == [255,255,255], axis=2)] = [0,0,0]
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-phase2.png', na)

# Do some morphology on edges - erode edges of white parts and then see what has changed
grey = cv2.cvtColor(na, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)              # Go to greyscale
SE = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))   # Get structuring element for morphology
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(grey, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, SE)       # Erode edges
edges = mask != grey                                     # Highlight what got eroded, i.e. differences
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-phase3.png', edges*255)

# Blacken the edges we have found in the copy of the original
orig[edges] = 0
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-phase4.png', orig)
```

I downsized your image to this:

[image]

And get these results:

`DEBUG-phase1.png`

[image]

`DEBUG-phase2.png`

[image]

`DEBUG-phase3.png`

[image]

`DEBUG-phase4.png`

[image]

---

Note: As @nick suggests in the comments, you could replace phase 3 where I do some morphology with a call to `cv2.findContours()` and `cv2.drawContours()` - and that is probably easier.

That would make the code look like this:

```
...
...
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-phase2.png', na)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(grey,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
res = cv2.drawContours(orig, contours, 0, (0, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-contours.png', res)
```

[image]

---

Note: You can do almost exactly the same without writing any Python, just in Terminal with **ImageMagick** on macOS, Linux or Windows:

```
magick start.png -fill white -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' DEBUG-phase1.png
magick DEBUG-phase1.png -fill black +opaque white DEBUG-phase2.png
magick DEBUG-phase2.png -morphology edge-in rectangle:3 DEBUG-phase3.png
```

Or, in a single command:

```
magick start.png \
   \(                                                \
      +clone -fill white -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
      -fill black +opaque white                      \
      -morphology edge-in rectangle:5 -negate        \
    \) -compose darken -composite result.png
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with it, the DEBUG-phase2 image could also be used to run cv2.findContours() and get values for area or bounding rectangle for the extracted section.

Comment: @nick Yes, thank you - there are lots of ways you could go.

Comment: My goal is to produce an image as in the original posting, this means the fill should have the same color, and the only thing that I'm essentially interested in adding or changing is the border of the section. So, from these examples, is it possible to add the border parameter to floodfill? Or possibly overlay DEBUG-phase3 over the original image (by only keeping the edges opaque, and the background transparent)?

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas: Use cvMat::copyTo() with your source image, a complete black one and DEBUG-phase3.png as a mask. That will paint everything thats white in the mask black in your color image.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copyto#mat-copyto

Comment: As for DEBUG-phase4 which except for the white color seems close to the desired result, one can do another floodfill (`ImageDraw.floodfill(img, (0,0), value=pixels[0,0])`) to get back to the original color.

Comment: DEBUG-contours looks a bit artifact-y / less visually pleasing with the inconsistent number of contour pixels, so I might still prefer going the other route with DEBUG-phase4.

Comment: Rather than refilling the white with the original colour, we could extract our copy of the original sooner - before filling with white.

Comment: You can make edges thinner and less artefacty by drawing the contours with thinner lines and/or using a smaller structuring element.